# Change date to work in correlation matrix

Tags: python, data-analysis, correlation

I am trying to create a correlation matrix to see which variables are useful from my dataset since there are over 600 variables.

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfbWt.png)

I used df.corr() and received an error message that Python cound not convert string into a float.
It was the date column. It is set up as YYYYmM or 2019m5 (2019 month 5(May). Do I just need to change the format? If so, how would I do that for the matrix to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Correlation can only be mathematically calculated with numerical data**.

If you want to perform this calculation, choose all numerical data types using the code

```
df.select_dtypes(include='number')
```

I recommend starting your data visualization with scatterplot and heatmap!